# Given i.i.d. random variables $X, Y \sim N(0, 1)$, find the conditional distribution of $X$ given that $X + Y > 0.$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian

Given i.i.d. random variables $X, Y \sim N(0, 1)$, find the conditional distribution of $X$ given that $X + Y > 0.$

First approach: Find the conditional CDF of $X$ given $X+Y >0$ :

$F_X(x | X+Y >0 ) = \mathbb{P}[X<x | X+Y > 0 ] = \mathbb{P}[X+Y >0 | X<x] \cdot \frac{\mathbb{P}[X<x]}{\mathbb{P}[X+Y >0 ]}$.

Notice that $X+Y \sim N(0,2)$ and so $\mathbb{P}[X+Y >0 ] = \frac{1}{2}$

However I cannot seem to calculate nicely $\mathbb{P}[X+Y >0 | X<x]$

Is there a better way to approach this problem? Can someone calculate  $\mathbb{P}[X+Y >0 | X<x] $, I am going to differentiate it anyways so It can be as an integral.

Comment: One could start with $\mathbb P[X+Y>0\mid X<x]=\mathbb P(X+Y>0,X<x)/\mathbb P[X<x]$.

Comment: $X+Y\sim N(0,2)$ and so $P[X+Y>0]=1/2$
Then
$$\begin{align}
P[X\leq a|X+Y>0]&=2P[X\leq a,X+Y>0]=\frac{1}{\pi}\int^a_{-\infty}\int^\infty_{-x}e^{-y^2/2}\,dye^{-x^2/2}\,dx\\
&=2\int^a_{-\infty}(1-\Phi(-x))\phi(x)=2\int^a_{-\infty}\Phi(x)\phi(x)\,dx\\
&=2(\Phi^2(x)|^a_{-\infty}-\int^a_{-\infty}\Phi(x)\phi(x)\,dx\Big)\\
&=2\Phi^2(a)-2\int^a_{-\infty}\Phi(x)\phi(x)\,dx
\end{align}$$ 
Then
$2\int^a_{-\infty}\Phi(x)\phi(x)\,dx =\Phi^2(a)$
That is $P[X\leq a|X+Y]=\Phi^2(a)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Phi(x):=\mathbb P(X\le x)$ be the c.d.f. of the standard $\mathcal N(0,1)$ distribution, and recall that $\Phi(-x)=1-\Phi(x)$. A way to proceed could be (I leave it for you to justify the steps):
\begin{align*}
\mathbb P(X\le x\mid X+Y>0)
&=\frac{\mathbb P(X\le x,X+Y>0)}{\mathbb P(X+Y>0)}\\[.4em]
&=\frac{\displaystyle\int_{-x}^\infty\mathbb P(-y<X\le x)\,\mathrm d\Phi(y)}{\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^\infty\mathbb P(-y<X)\,\mathrm d\Phi(y)}\\[.4em]
&=\frac{\mathbb E[(\Phi(x)-\Phi(-Y))\mathbf 1_{\{Y\ge -x\}}]}{\mathbb E[\Phi(Y)]}\\[.4em]
&=\frac{\Phi(x)^2–\mathbb E[\Phi(Y)\mathbf 1_{\{Y\le x\}}]}{\mathbb E[\Phi(Y)]}.
\end{align*}
To further simplify this one could use that $\Phi(Y)$ is uniformly distributed on $(0,1)$.